# Video embedding

Tags: python, django, web-applications, video-embedding

I have a Django site that I want to add videos. Currently users can upload their photos and I want each user to be able to add their videos as well. I am not sure how to do this, since I am a beginner programmer. Can you please direct me to right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling video files is much more complicated than dealing with images. There are two ways you can do it: you let users embed videos uploaded to other sites (like youtube) or you let them upload photos to your website. The first option is easier: most of the video websites offer some way to copy&paste a code to embed their videos on other sites. You just need to let users paste the html code on your website and there are some security measures you should take care of. 
If you want them to upload the files it's getting hard.There are many video formats, files are much bigger, different compression rates etc. A video site usually accepts a wide range of video formats, converts a video to the most convenient format and different resolutions (to save space and bandwidth). It means a lot of asynchronous and CPU intensive tasks on your server.
It's also more complicated to put the file on the website and let it play.
There's a video tag in HTML5 that makes things much easier than before although if you want to make it really nice and easy you should find some JS player.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, actually the way to upload a video is same as like you upload the photo (or add video format to your current POST file method if there is a file format validation), please learn about [Django File Upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/), and try to leave some code in your description